# PHP if statement checking variable is empty issue

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, pdo

This is driving me nuts, I have a login function that checks to make sure that the users credentials are correct, and also checks to see if an 'activation' field for that user is empty (if it wasn't, it means that they haven't activated yet and therefore shouldn't be able to log in). If all of those conditions check out fine, it returns a user id in a variable, and if not it returns `false`.

### Function

The function runs correctly right up until I add the if statement that checks if the variable `$activation` is empty, using `empty()`. If the field is truly empty, it returns the user_id like it's supposed to, but if the field isn't empty and still contains the 40 char activation code - it also lets the user log in. Which is ridiculous.

Here is the login function (with irrelevant portions removed):

```
function loginCheck($email, $password) {

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `salt`,`activation` FROM `users` WHERE `email`= :email LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
    $salt = $stmt->fetchColumn(0);
    $activation = $stmt->fetchColumn(1);

    if (empty($activation)) {

    // another few unrelated tasks and query here to grab user id which is returned below

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            return $stmt->fetchColumn(1); // the returned user ID
        } else {
            return false;
        }       
    } else {
        return false; // It should return this false here because the field IS NOT empty!
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

}

1) I have performed the first query manually, and it does in fact select the fields `salt` and `activation` flawlessly.

2) I have checked to make sure that the column being fetched and applied to the var `$activation` is correct, it is the second column so `$activation = $stmt->fetchColumn(1)` is fine.

### Page

Now on the `login.php` page which calls the above function, here is the code relating to calling the function and logging in:

```
$login = loginCheck($email, $password);

if ($login === false) {
    $errors[] = 'Unable to log you in';
}

if (!empty($errors)) {
foreach ($errors as $error) {
echo $error, '<br />'; 
}
} else {
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
header('Location: you/default.php');
exit();
}
```

I've looked and looked and can't find any errors. Why on earth is this occurring?

## EDIT

The activation field in my MySQL table is set to `varchar(40)` with a collation of `utf8_general_ci`, and since the activation field is populated with numbers and letters, I'm assuming it's a string.

And yes, the user_id that is returned is the one that relates to the user logging in, so that is correct.

Comment: When it allows the login, does `$_SESSION['user_id']` still equal the correct user ID?

Comment: There are only 3 places it can return a FALSE. Since you say that $salt was reached, that leaves 2. What data type is `$activation`?

Comment: I've added an additional section to my question, which answers these questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php,

> There is no way to return another column from the same row if you use
>   PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve data.

This is because each time you call fetchColumn it will apply over the row next to the row on which the previous call applied.

```
 $salt = $stmt->fetchColumn(0);
$activation = $stmt->fetchColumn(1);
```

The second call to fetchColumn() is working over the row next to that of the first call. In your case, as there is only one row, fetchColumn() returns NULL, so that's why activation appears as empty.

Use fetch() to retrieve an array with all the values of the row:

```
   $row=$stmt->fetch();
   $salt=$row[0];
   $activation=$row[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! PDO is giving me such a hard time, how can I therefore grab multiple fields from the same row and fetch them?

Comment: Ok, let me add it to my answer.

Comment: Perfect! it works now. Good explanation as well, I would never of thought to think that the issue was being caused by the way in which fetchColumn() works. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this approach..

**Columns**

```
`activation_code` varchar(40) not null,
`activated` tinyint(1) not null default '0',
```

Now create an activate function elsewhere, once complete update activated === 1 for the user

When you do you login check, consider:

1. Check Username
2. Check Password
3. Check activated === 1

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using 'char' data type in the database for the activation. So you better try this code.

```
if (trim($activation)!= "") 
{

}
```

Cheers!

Prasad.

Comment: The `empty` function accounts for empty strings, so his statement and your solution are equivalent as far as I know.

Comment: I'd prefer to find why the string is coming back with spaces in the first place - that would indicate something is not working as it should elsewhere.

Comment: If you use 'char' (40) data type. It always has 'spaces' for rest of characters. Anyway this is depend on your insert query.

Comment: When I said empty string I just meant `""`, not strings that are full of whitespace. I see what Prasad is doing now (`trim`).

Comment: Yes. I used trim to remove any whitespaces.

Comment: I've added an additional section to my question, which answers these questions.

Comment: Hi Antilogical. Thanks In that case my solution won't work either. Let's see what the issue is..